# CDS Client Data Set files - is there an alternative way to manipulate these?

Tags: c++, delphi, com, mfc, tclientdataset

I have a C++ application that historically uses a Delphi IClientTable interface (MIDAS.DLL??) to maintain a local file database (.CDS file). Within our C++ application, IClientTable is a COleDispatchDriver MFC interface/object.

I would personally like to move away from this altogether and use SQLite, but unfortunately I am not in the position to do this right now.

Can somebody please tell me if there is an open source replacement for this COM overhead? I would like a simple DLL, library or set of source files to compile into my program to get rid of the COM interface which is causing me so much grief.

If you really want to know why I want rid of the COM interface - its odd - we've used it for 10 years without problem. Recently we've found a customer with Windows XP Embedded and for some reason when we use the IClientTable COM dispatch interface, this causes Windows WM_QUERYENDSESSION messages to be absorbed, or no longer reach my application. The minute I stop using the IClientTable interface, I get the WM_QUERYENDSESSION messages.

In short: the IClientTable COM dispatch interface appears to stop Windows from being allowed to log off/shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any alternative ways to open binary ClientDataSet files. ClientDataSets can use also use an XML file format but I don't know if your IClientTable interface gives you access to that functionality.

If you weren't aware of this already the ClientDataSet's dependency on COM was removed in I think either Delphi 2007 or Delphi 2009. Recompiling your wrapper DLL in a recent version of Delphi may help, *if* the COM dependency comes from the ClientDataSet.

To the best of my knowledge there is no such thing as an IClientTable in any version of Delphi. I'm guessing that IClientTable is part of a wrapper DLL written by your team to encapsulate the ClientDataSet's features. If whoever wrote that wrapper DLL exposed the IClientTable interface as a COM object that may also be part of reason for your dependency on COM.

Comment: Yes, the IClientTable is a wrapper that our team created for the TClientDataSet Delphi class. I'm told that DCOM was removed (??) but the source that I have for Midas indicates that it still uses COM.. I have toyed with the idea of exposing DLL function from a modified Midas.dll but I believe the majority of the work is done by the TClientDataSet class anyway.. so more than likely we're going to be forced away from using ClientDataSet (which I'd be more than happy to do).

Comment: in fact it's not that hard to write your own cds binary format parser. I did that in my own midas version based on hyperbase

Comment: True Vavan..  I personally would prefer to simply dump CDS altogether and move to SQLite for what we have but its all about risk and what I am and aren't allowed to change this late in the project prior to imminent release. I would really like to have the ability to pinpoint this with a tool like WinDbg so there can be no question of what is causing the problem.. but I don't know how to do that unless I hook into the SendMessage API call via the kernel debugger..

Comment: you could try to use something like rohitab API Monitor tool to figure out who's the culprit